# TypeScript: Why does empty interface or type alias allow any thing?

Tags: typescript

What does an **empty interface** mean in TypeScript?  And why does it act like type `: any`, which seems to opt-out of type checking?

```
interface PersonA {}
const person1: PersonA = { name: 'Chester', age: 3 } // OK
const person2: PersonA = "Chuck" // OK
```

What does an **empty type alias** mean in TypeScript?  Why does it also act like basic type `: any` without any type enforcement?

```
type PersonB = {}
const person3: PersonB = { color: 'red' } // OK
const person4: PersonB = 5 // OK
```

Searching through https://www.typescriptlang.org  I haven't found an answer yet.

**Q)** Where can I find more information about this in the official TypeScript docs?

Example: https://repl.it/repls/OrnateResponsibleTelephones

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question was prompted by some code I found in our codebase:
`export type PersonResponse = IPersonResponse | {}` that I think may be incorrect, as NO typing is enforced.  I think the pervious developer wanted to ensure an empty object was possible.

Comment: The [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) really just says that this *is* true without saying why: object types in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936); you can always extend interfaces by adding properties.  So a value of type `{a: string}` may well have a `b` property, since `{a: string, b: number} extends {a: string}` is true.  The object type with no defined properties, `{}`, can be extended by any other object type (e.g., `{name: string, age: number} extends {}` is true).

Comment: Thanks for this: [(Microsoft Official TypeScript FAQ)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces)